# How to transform and get coordinates/shapes from results of MMDetection?

Tags: python, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

[Official demo](https://mmdetection.readthedocs.io/en/latest/1_exist_data_model.html) shows we could use `show_result(img, result, out_file='result.jpg')` api to draw results on a picture.

```py
model = init_detector('configs/any-config.py', 'checkpoints/any-checkpoints.pth', device='cpu')
results = inference_detector(model, 'some_pic.png')
model.show_result('some_pic.png', results, 'some_pic_results.png')
```

In debug tool I found format of `results` is a tuple contains `list[][]`. How should we get coordinates/shapes from it?

[image]

Is there a more detailed description for that format, or a direct api which could transform `results` into a more easy-to-use json (such as a COCO dataset format)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay that, I combined several methods and got a usable method. 
If you guys have a better way please let me know.

convert_polygon:

```py
# this method combined:
# mmdetection.mmdet.models.detectors.base.BaseDetector.show_result
# open-mmlab\Lib\site-packages\mmdet\core\visualization\image.py imshow_det_bboxes, draw_bboxes, draw_labels, draw_masks
def convert_polygon(
        result,
        score_thr=0.3,

):
    from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
    import numpy as np
    import torch
    import cv2

    ms_bbox_result, ms_segm_result = result
    if isinstance(ms_bbox_result, dict):
        result = (ms_bbox_result['ensemble'],
                  ms_segm_result['ensemble'])

    if isinstance(result, tuple):
        bbox_result, segm_result = result
        if isinstance(segm_result, tuple):
            segm_result = segm_result[0]  # ms rcnn
    else:
        bbox_result, segm_result = result, None
    bboxes = np.vstack(bbox_result)
    labels = [
        np.full(bbox.shape[0], i, dtype=np.int32)
        for i, bbox in enumerate(bbox_result)
    ]
    labels = np.concatenate(labels)
    # draw segmentation masks
    segms = segm_result
    if segm_result is not None and len(labels) > 0:  # non empty
        segms = mmcv.concat_list(segm_result)
        if isinstance(segms[0], torch.Tensor):
            segms = torch.stack(segms, dim=0).detach().cpu().numpy()
        else:
            segms = np.stack(segms, axis=0)

    assert bboxes is None or bboxes.ndim == 2, \
        f' bboxes ndim should be 2, but its ndim is {bboxes.ndim}.'
    assert labels.ndim == 1, \
        f' labels ndim should be 1, but its ndim is {labels.ndim}.'
    assert bboxes is None or bboxes.shape[1] == 4 or bboxes.shape[1] == 5, \
        f' bboxes.shape[1] should be 4 or 5, but its {bboxes.shape[1]}.'
    assert bboxes is None or bboxes.shape[0] <= labels.shape[0], \
        'labels.shape[0] should not be less than bboxes.shape[0].'
    assert segms is None or segms.shape[0] == labels.shape[0], \
        'segms.shape[0] and labels.shape[0] should have the same length.'
    assert segms is not None or bboxes is not None, \
        'segms and bboxes should not be None at the same time.'

    if score_thr > 0:
        assert bboxes is not None and bboxes.shape[1] == 5
        scores = bboxes[:, -1]
        inds = scores > score_thr
        bboxes = bboxes[inds, :]
        labels = labels[inds]
        if segms is not None:
            segms = segms[inds, ...]

    num_bboxes = 0
    ret_label = None
    ret_bbox = None
    ret_polygon = None
    ret_area = None
    ret_position = None
    ret_mask = None
    if bboxes is not None:
        num_bboxes = bboxes.shape[0]
        ret_bbox = bboxes
        ret_polygon = []
        for i, bbox in enumerate(bboxes):
            bbox_int = bbox.astype(np.int32)
            poly = [[bbox_int[0], bbox_int[1]], [bbox_int[0], bbox_int[3]],
                    [bbox_int[2], bbox_int[3]], [bbox_int[2], bbox_int[1]]]
            np_poly = np.array(poly).reshape((4, 2))
            ret_polygon.append(Polygon(np_poly))
        ret_label = labels[:num_bboxes]

    if segms is not None:
        ret_mask = []
        for i, mask in enumerate(segms):
            temp_mask = []
            from mmdet.core.mask.structures import bitmap_to_polygon
            contours, _ = bitmap_to_polygon(mask)
            temp_mask += [Polygon(c) for c in contours]
            ret_mask.append(temp_mask)

        if num_bboxes < segms.shape[0]:
            segms = segms[num_bboxes:]
            areas = []
            positions = []
            for mask in segms:
                _, _, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(
                    mask.astype(np.uint8), connectivity=8)
                largest_id = np.argmax(stats[1:, -1]) + 1
                positions.append(centroids[largest_id])
                areas.append(stats[largest_id, -1])
            areas = np.stack(areas, axis=0)
            ret_area = areas
            ret_position = positions

    return {'labels': ret_label,
            'bboxes': ret_bbox,
            'polygons': ret_polygon,
            'areas': ret_area,
            'positions': ret_position,
            'masks': ret_mask}
```

Key part of those code:

```py
ret_mask = []
for i, mask in enumerate(segms):
    temp_mask = []
    from mmdet.core.mask.structures import bitmap_to_polygon
    contours, _ = bitmap_to_polygon(mask)
    temp_mask += [Polygon(c) for c in contours]
    ret_mask.append(temp_mask)
```

test code:

```py
model = init_detector(config_file, checkpoint_file, device='cpu')
results = inference_detector(model, test_pic_file)
poly = convert_polygon(results)
```

After converting `poly` into json, format would be like this:

```json
{
    "labels": [1, 1, 2, ...],
    "bboxes": [
            [499.54632568359375, 0.0, 599.1744384765625, 332.5544128417969, 0.9999723434448242],
            ...
    ],
    "polygons": [
        [ [499.0, 0.0], [499.0, 332.0], [599.0, 332.0], [599.0, 0.0], [499.0, 0.0] ],
        ...
    ],
    ...
    ],
    "areas": null,
    "positions": null,
    "masks": [
        [
            [
                [510.0, 0.0],
                [509.0, 1.0],
                [508.0, 1.0],
                ...
            ],
            ...
        ],
        ...
    ],
}
```

Some fields are easy to guess.

- `labels` are the `class id` of every instance
- The first 4 numbers in `bboxes` are `left-top-x, left-top-y, right-bottom-x, right-bottom-y` of the bounding boxes in rectangle shape. The last number of `bboxes` is confidence value of that instance
- `polygons` contains coordinate value which are the same to above
- no idea about `areas` and `positions` because they are always `null` when testing
- `masks` contains coordinates arrays of instances. Only one array if there is no holes in that instance

---

2023-07-31 update:

Recently I work on MMDetection again and found its APIs were changed a lot. Most important change is that in MMDetection3, return type of `inference_detector` become `DetDataSample`.

Any new updates would be pushed to [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/FirokOtaku/AlloyWrench/blob/main/src/main/python/firok/tool/alloywrench/convert_result.py).